# Do number sentiments work?

Tags: riddle, mathematics

We are of a family of eleven
When we join or depart numbers less than a cent
Excepting those special ten
We turn odd to even and even to odd
Like a tiny miracle of god
However, in general our company results in swap
Of the original ones, an easy sum for a clever chap

Hint 1:

> If you add 09 to those (...) set of numbers...you get swapped result, similarly adding 18,..and with the exceptions to this being,....

What are we and what are those exceptions ?

Answer (score 2):

Are they

> Multiples of 11 and the exceptions are the first ten even multiples of 11.

My reasoning:

We are of a family of eleven

> Taking it's literal meaning to be numbers which are multiple of 11

When we join or depart numbers less than a cent

> This means if we add or subtract from numbers which are less than 100

Excepting those special ten

We turn odd to even and even to odd

> If we add odd multiples of 11 to a odd number it becomes even and to even number it becomes odd. So the exceptions are the even multiples of 11.

Like a tiny miracle of god

However, in general our company results in swap

Of the original ones, an easy sum for a clever chap

> Here the swap means a number 'ab' becomes 'ba'. As we clearly know 'ab'+'ba'=11n. We see that using the right multiple of 11 we can swap the number. For example, if our number is 23 then 23 + 32 = 55 = 11 * 5. So, in the company of multiples of 11 we can swap numbers.

This is just my working, although I might be far off.

Comment: Well, in the near right track, but requiring corrections

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Requiring corrections in explanations of this solution? Or the solution itself is wrong? Because I have something else that *might* fit.

Comment: @Rand... please post your solution, as CMSnoob's answer I cannot consider as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the previous answer, but different:

> you are multiples of $9$.

*We are of a family of eleven

When we join or depart numbers less than a cent*

> $9,18,27,36,45,54,63,72,81,90,99$ - these are the family of eleven numbers you get by multiplying $9$ with numbers less than ten.

*Excepting those special ten

We turn odd to even and even to odd

Like a tiny miracle of god*

> If you multiply $9$ by something with an odd number of digits, you get something with an even number of digits, and vice versa - unless the number is less than $11...1$. Those aren't just ten exceptions though, so probably there's a better explanation for this clue.

*However, in general our company results in swap

Of the original ones*

> Swapping the digits in any of $9,18,27,36,45,54,63,72,81,90,99$ keeps you within the same set.

*an easy sum for a clever chap*

> Summing the digits of any multiple of $9$ gives another multiple of $9$.

I'm not sure about all of the clues, but this seems like it *might* fit?

Comment: Yes, you are in the right track, @Rand al'Thor. First explanation is correct. Remaining ones require edit to accept this as a correct answer.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Even the very last spoilertag isn't correct? That was one of the giveaways for me, the digit sum property.

Comment: No, not. That line is  just for dramatization/ poetic purposes.